# Android does not make director(mkdir)

Tags: android

**SOLVED**

i change  it a litle bit

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AndroidPaint");
        File file = new File(path, tmpImg);
        path.mkdirs();
        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        source.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```

also problem could be source Bitmap i discovered then was null

**PROBLEM**

on my Android program i want save bitmap on external store i got permission for do that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and got some code for that

```
public class SaveOpen {
public static void save(Bitmap source) {
    String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myapp");
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("save", "Directory not created");
        }
        File file = new File(dir, tmpImg);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        source.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("save", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

but when i press save button on my app i get

> open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)

exception, what i do wrong.? i tried all guide i found in google, pls help

Comment: try this,
remove `if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("save", "Directory not created");
        }`
And change this
`File file = new File(dir, tmpImg);
 file.mkdirs();
        if(!file.exists()) {`

Comment: @Varun still > open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String myDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp";

File dir = new File(myDir);
```

Comment: @Mariusz : use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);` for save image or file

Answer (score 0):

On older devices access to external storge is not possible if there's is USB connection (disk mode), so log what is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returning in your case.

Comment: i work on emulator but on real device(unpluged) also cant create director

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, it seems like a bug on Android, I mkdir in the command line by adb, also failed. Then I try to restart the phone, never happen again.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by add permissions to access external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```